# facing a problem Dividing the maximum length of a string using substr PHP

Tags: php

I'm facing a problem with dividing the maximum number by itself.
Example, the number is

```
6667880025043855
```

which is max length is 16, so I will divide it into four digits with four breaks in every number

Example:

```
6667
8800
2504
3855
```

So what I did is using substr and dividing it by four.

The code:

```
if (strlen($number) == 16) { // instaces if the max length is 16.
  echo $number1 = substr($number, 0, 4)."</br>"; 
   echo $number2 = substr($number, 4, 8)."</br>";
   echo $number3 = substr($number, 8, 12)."</br>";
   echo $number4 = substr($number, 12, 16)."</br>";
}
```

But my output would be:

```
6667
88002504
25043855
3855
```

Am I doing it wrong? 
P.S: 
I'm still in the beginner's phase.

Comment: According to [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) 3rd parameter is length not end index.

Comment: I see, so it would be substr($number, the number to be subtracted, length). Now I get it, thank you too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should research the function in here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
The third param is the number of characters in your substr.

It should be:

```
$number = '6667880025043855';

if (strlen($number) == 16) { // instaces if the max length is 16.
  echo $number1 = substr($number, 0, 4)."</br>"; 
   echo $number2 = substr($number, 4, 4)."</br>";
   echo $number3 = substr($number, 8, 4)."</br>";
   echo $number4 = substr($number, 12, 4)."</br>";
}
```

Comment: Actually that is my basis of doing this. The second example indicates that $rest = substr("abcdef", 2, -1);  // returns "cde". So I assumed that subtracting the first two returns with cdef and the end is negative one so I assumed it would be minus the last length withe negative one so it got "cde". I really had hard time finding the results but I won't stop learning. thank you sir, worked as charm.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `chunk_split` to split the number into pieces?

```
$number=6667880025043855;
$length=4;
$chunks=chunk_split( strval($number), $length );

printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($chunks,true));
```

Will yield:

```
6667
8800
2504
3855
```

Or, if you need as separate variables:

```
$chunks=explode( PHP_EOL, chunk_split( strval( $number ), $length ) );
```

then you can access each number, like this:

```
echo $chunks[1];// yields 8800 etc
```